# Understanding CaseIterable in swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I've read the documentation, and seen perhaps only a part of what the protocol is. I just am not following the logic. Can someone help me understand this?

What I see in xcode when I examine the protocol

```
/// Conforming to the CaseIterable Protocol
/// =======================================
///
/// The compiler can automatically provide an implementation of the
/// `CaseIterable` requirements for any enumeration without associated values
/// or `@available` attributes on its cases. The synthesized `allCases`
/// collection provides the cases in order of their declaration.
///
/// You can take advantage of this compiler support when defining your own
/// custom enumeration by declaring conformance to `CaseIterable` in the
/// enumeration's original declaration. The `CompassDirection` example above
/// demonstrates this automatic implementation.
public protocol CaseIterable {

    /// A type that can represent a collection of all values of this type.
    associatedtype AllCases : Collection = [Self] where Self == Self.AllCases.Element

    /// A collection of all values of this type.
    static var allCases: Self.AllCases { get }
}
```

I'm struggling to follow what is happening here and why. Can someone walk me through the logic of this please?

One of the other big struggles I'm having because of this is if I conform a protocol to be CaseIterable.

```
protocol Foo: CaseIterable {}
```

I can't use it as a variable anymore.

```
struct Bar {
    var foo: Foo
}
```

I get this error
`Protocol 'Foo' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

It does have Self requirements but I can't figure out how to get around this problem. If someone could help me understand why this happens and how to fix it too, I'd be very grateful.

---

Edit: - This is the playground code copied directly. I've updated it to use the some, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed past this error.

```
import Foundation

protocol Zot: CaseIterable {
    var prop: Data { get }
}

enum Bar: Zot {
    case thing3
    case thing4

    var prop: Data {
        switch self {
        case .thing3, .thing4: return Data()
        }
    }

    init() {}
}

enum Baz: Zot {
    case thing1
    case thing2

    var prop: Data {
        switch self {
        case .thing1, .thing2: return Data()
        }
    }

    init() {}
}

enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz

    var otherValues: some Zot {
        switch self {
        case .bar:
            return Bar
        case .baz:
            return Baz
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CaseIterable is to be used together with enumerations and it's not some protocol you use with any arbitrary type and the error you get is in no way specific to this protocol. So in this case `foo` should be declared as `var foo: FooEnum` where the `FooEnum` enumeration conforms to `CaseIterable`

Comment: You *can* use it for types other than `enum` types, but the compiler won't synthesize conformance for you.  Another category of types where I have occasionally found it useful are `struct` types that conform to `OptionSet`.  In that case you have to define the `AllCases` associated type, and manually add new elements to `allCases` property.

Comment: As for the other problem, Swift 5.7 relaxed the rules for Self and associated type requirements.  You should be able to use `any` to define `Bar` the way you want: `struct Bar { var foo: any Foo }`.

Comment: The problem is not with `CaseIterable`, but because `Foo` is a protocol, so you must declare `var foo: some Foo`.

Comment: @ChipJarred, HunterLion - I didn't know that I could use some or any as keywords prior to the type being looked for. Thank you

Comment: @HunterLion, This does silence the error that I'm getting, but if I try to make this a computed property and return a value conforming to Foo, it tells me `Type 'Baz.Type' cannot conform to 'Foo'`. Is there a way to make this return properly too? This so far seems to be working the best, just trying to understand better.

Comment: @TinyTim, `some` has only been a part of Swift for a few years now, so in the grand scheme of things it's relatively new.  `any` is even newer.  Lots of code as well as learning material online predate them.  Anyway, Swift is a bit of a moving target and keeping up with it can be a challenge, especially if you're busy actually working in an existing code base.

Comment: Aye, I've mostly been just plodding through work, but thought I'd start a personal project finally. I've done a lot that I didn't know how to do before and run into a lot of errors I didn't know existed. All-in-all, this has been a very educational experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CaseIterable` exists to allow you to programmatically walk through all the possible cases of an `enum`, allowing you use the `enum` type as a `Collection` of its cases:

```swift
enum CardinalDirection: CaseIterable { case north, south, east, west }

for direction in CardinalDirection.allCases {
    // Do something with direction which is one of north, south, east, west
    print("\(direction)")
}
```

This prints

```
north
south
east
west
```

There is nothing that prevents you from making other kinds of types conform to `CaseIterable`; however, the compiler will only synthesize conformance for `enum` types.  It's not useful for most other kinds of types; however, I have occasionally found it useful for types that conform to `OptionSet`.  In that case you have to manually implement conformance.

```swift
struct AssetFlags: OptionSet, CaseIterable
{
    typealias RawValue = UInt8
    typealias AllCases = [AssetFlags]

    let rawValue: RawValue

    static let shouldPreload = AssetFlags(rawValue: 0x01)
    static let isPurgeable   = AssetFlags(rawValue: 0x02)
    static let isLocked      = AssetFlags(rawValue: 0x04)
    static let isCached      = AssetFlags(rawValue: 0x08)

    static var allCases: AllCases = [shouldPreload, isPurgeable, isLocked, isCached]
}
```

Note that `OptionSet` is conceptually similar to an `enum`.  They both define a small set of distinct values they can have.  With one they are mutually exclusive, while for the other they may be combined.  But the key thing for `CaseIterable` to be useful is the finite nature of the set of possible distinct values.  If your type has that characteristic, conforming to `CaseIterable` could be useful, otherwise, it wouldn't make sense.  `Int` or `String`, for example, are *not* good candidates for `CaseIterable`.

In my own code, I don't bother conforming to `CaseIterable`, even for `enum` types, until a specific need arises that requires it.  Actually I take that approach to all protocol conformance.  It's a specific case of the more general YAGNI rule of thumb: "You ain't gonna need it."

Regarding your `Bar` struct, the problem is not specifically related to `CaseIterable`, but rather to using a protocol with Self or associated type requirements, which for `Foo` happens to be inherited from `CaseIterable`.

Swift 5.7 relaxed the rules concerning Self and associated type requirements a bit, allowing you to use the `any` keyword to tell the compiler you want to use an existential `Foo` instead of a concrete `Foo` to write

```swift
struct Bar {
   var foo: any Foo
}
```

If you want a concrete `Foo` you could use `some`.  The original way to do it though, which still works, is to make `Bar` explicitly generic

```swift
struct Bar<T: Foo> {
   var foo: T
}
```

### Update based on revised question code

The way you're using `enums` is... well, let's say it's out of the ordinary.  There are two problems.  The first is that you're returning *types* not *values*:

```swift
enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz

    // Will return a *value* of a type that conforms to Zot
    var otherValues: some Zot 
    {
        switch self {
            case .bar:
                return Bar // Bar is a *type* not a value
            case .baz:
                return Baz // Baz is a *type* not a value
        }
    }
}
```

I'll fix this is in a way that is almost certainly wrong for what you want to do, but allows moving forward to the other problem.  We need to return values, so I'll just pick the first of the corresponding cases of `Bar` and `Baz`, and that will expose the other problem.

```swift
enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz

    var otherValues: some Zot 
    {
        switch self {
           case .bar: return Bar.thing3 
           case .baz: return Baz.thing1 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `some` means that there will be one specific concrete type that conforms to `Zot`, so the compiler will be able to access its properties and methods directly rather than via its protocol witness table... it's basically a way to have the efficiency of having the calling code use the concrete types without having to tie to calling code to the concrete type at the source code level.  `otherValues`, however, returns a value of either of *two* types, so the return type would have to be an *existential* type rather than a concrete one.  You could do this if you return `any Zot` instead of `some Zot`.

Of course even using `any`, this version is wrong, because it doesn't take into account half of the cases of `Bar` and `Baz`. I assume that you want to be able to construct a `Foo` from a `Bar` or `Baz` while preserving its original value somehow, and I guess retrieve it later.

Before I present solutions, I want to mention that without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, your code feels like it took a wrong design turn at some point.  It would probably be better to rethink how you're doing what you want to do to see if there is a better way.

If I understand what your trying to do, I can think of at least three of ways, none of which requires `CaseIterable`, but maybe that's needed for other reasons.

#### Option 1

The first is to define `Foo` so that it explicitly contains all of the cases of `Bar` and `Baz`:

```swift
enum Foo: Zot
{
    case thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4

    init(_ value: Bar) 
    {
        switch value
        {
            case .thing3: self = .thing3
            case .thing4: self = .thing4
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Baz)
    {
        switch value
        {
            case .thing1: self = .thing1
            case .thing2: self = .thing2
        }
    }

    var prop: Data 
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .thing1: return Baz.thing1.prop
            case .thing2: return Baz.thing2.prop
            case .thing3: return Bar.thing3.prop
            case .thing4: return Bar.thing4.prop
        }
    }

    var bazValue: Baz?
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .thing1: return .thing1
            case .thing2: return .thing2
            default: return nil
        }
    }

    var barValue: Bar?
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .thing3: return .thing3
            case .thing4: return .thing4
            default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of being straight-forward, but will require more maintenance if you add/remove cases from `Bar` or `Baz` - or even add a whole other `enum` that conforms to `Zot`.

#### Option 2

The second way is to define `Foo` so that it uses associated values:

```swift
enum Foo
{
    case bar(value: Bar)
    case baz(value: Baz)

    init(_ value: Bar) { self = .bar(value: value) }
    init(_ value: Baz) { self = .baz(value: value) }
}
```

I think this second case is cleaner, and you don't need `otherValues` because usage code can do:

```swift
switch foo
{
    case let .bar(value: bar): 
        // do whatever with bar

    case let .baz(value: baz): 
        // do whatever with baz
}
```

Still assuming second version of `Foo`, maybe an even cleaner way is:

```swift
extension Foo
{
    func withZotValue<R>(_ code: (any Zot) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
    {
        switch self
        {
            case let .bar(value: value): return try code(value)
            case let .baz(value: value): return try code(value)
        }
    }
}
```

That allows you to eliminate a lot of `switch` statements in usage code. To use it:

```swift
foo.withZotValue { zotValue in
    // Do something with zotValue that the Zot protocol supports.
}
```

If you need this second version of `Foo` to conform to `CaseIterable`, Swift won't synthesize conformance for you because of the associated values, but you can write the conformance yourself.

```swift
extension Foo: CaseIterable
{
    typealias AllCases = [Self]

    static var allCases: AllCases {
        [
            Baz.allCases.map { .baz(value: $0) },
            Bar.allCases.map { .bar(value: $0) },
        ].joined()
    }
}
```

#### Option 3:

The last possible solution, which actually should probably be the first, if it applies, would be to define whatever you're trying to do that's common to both `Bar` and `Baz` in `Zot`.  Whether that's a good idea or not depends on what you're trying to do, but let's assume it does make sense.  For example, I notice that both `Bar` and `Baz` support a `prop` property, but the `Zot` protocol doesn't list `prop`.  Why not? Is it unrelated to "Zotness"? If anything that conforms to `Zot` should have a `prop` property, then add it to the protocol:

```swift
protocol Zot: CaseIterable {
    var prop: Data { get }
}
```

You still provide implementations of `prop` in `Bar` and `Baz` - that's kind of like overriding a base class method in subclasses.

Let's say the `Data` returned from `prop` is encoded JSON and you want be able to decode a `Codable` thing from a `Zot`.  You can now do that without caring if its a `Bar` or a `Baz` (or any other new `Zot`-conforming type you might add later):

```swift
func decode<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, from src: some Zot) throws -> T {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: src.prop)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Chip. This does clarify things a lot. My setup is a bit complicated so I'd be hard pressed to share why I've been forced into this corner. Using `any` doesn't seem to quiet the error for me, but using some does. In a playground, I've setup an additional struct, `Baz`, which conforms to Foo (I set allCases to be an empty array), but if I try to set it to `var foo: some Foo`, I get the error `Type 'Baz.Type' cannot conform to 'Foo'`. Is there a way to still set this conformance to the variable?

Comment: I'd need to see the code (or a distilled example of it).  That error sounds like you're assigning the *type* `Baz` to `foo`, rather than a *value* of type, `Baz`. Maybe if you paste the assignment where you get the error, it will be more clear, though it's likely surrounding context will be necessary.

Comment: @TinyTim, if your playground is on GitHub as a public repo, I could take a look at it.  I'd just need the link.  Alternatively you could paste it (or relevant parts of it) into a gist, and give that link.

Comment: I've edited the main body of the question, I've copied the playground straight to it.

Comment: OK, there are a couple of problems.  `var otherValues: some Zot` means that `otherValues` will return a *value* of *one* specific concrete type that conforms to `Zot`, but your code returns *types* not values, and even they were values, they're  *two* different types, not one.

Comment: I appended to my answer to take into account the code you added to the question.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help understanding this.

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope one of the solutions I present is useful.

Comment: Yes, I think solutions 2 and 3 may both be applicable. I do recognize that I'm doing things in a fairly unconventional manner. I'd like to finish up this semi-project. And then I might make it public and ask for feedback. Needless to say, things have been delicate with the approach I've taken and I think you're right that something in the design has taken a wrong turn. I've definitely been fighting against swift to make it do what I want rather than working with it.

Comment: If you're almost done, you might not feel like refactoring into a better design is worth the time, but the sooner you do it, the easier the code will be to work with, which could mean finishing faster than if you don't refactor.  Even if you don't do it now, I would recommend doing it at some point.  Like anything else, software design is a skill that takes practice, and it sounds like your project is a good opportunity to get that practice.